# Can't swich between Ubuntu and Microsoft and am stuck in Ubuntu. Please help!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hibernate

In order to switch to Microsoft Windows 8.1 from Ubuntu I would go into my BIOS and click F8 to get to a menu where I can pick what to boot from. I clicked on my hard drive(were I have both Ubuntu and Windows) as usual. After that it should have gone into another menu were I could choose which operating system I wanted to boot into, but it didn't and it went straight into Ubuntu I am trying to fix it and so I went into settings and when I clicked on the section that shows the hard drive space partitioned for Windows it said this:

```
Unable to access "649 GB Volume"

Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/jd/543652053651E88E: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/jd/543652053651E88E"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this so I can get back into windows?

Answer (score 0):

This is a UEFI computer, correct? You need to go into the EFI settings, select boot EFI file, then it should give a menu with something like microsoft, ubuntu, blah blah blah. Select microsoft then select the EFI boot file for it and it should start windows. When it starts windows you should shut it down fully instead of hibernating or fast shutting it down. Also, please note that dual booting windows 8.x and linux of any kind is VERY unstable at this point and probably will be until windows changes how windows operates because at the moment trying to chain load into the windows bootloader ends up not going well at all and it is recommended to either use an external usb to boot into a full partition on the drive or even hot swap drives if you are okay with that type of thing.

Comment: Should I shut down while windows is loading?

Comment: you have to go into settings and select "shut down" in windows, or do a battery pull while it is on (though windows will probably scream at you for doing that as always)

Comment: How do I get to the EFI boot file

Comment: what kind of computer is it?

Comment: Cyberpower with an asus motherboard.

Comment: what does f11 do at startup?

Comment: The chat got to long. I press F2 at the start and not F11 to get to the BIOS or UEFI

Comment: but f11 should bring up a uefi prompt to select the boot file, I'm not talking about how to open bios settings

Comment: oh. Okay. Ill try. IDK if it will work though.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. I tried rebooted again and hit F2 the second time and it said I was in the UEFI BIOS Settings. Also do you think I could fix it by reinstalling windows with my Windows 8.1 disk? Z87-K

Comment: one moment I'll look up your board and the shortcut keys

Comment: you still there?

Comment: yeah. what motherboard do you have?

Comment: I have an asus Z87-K. Sorry I had to go for a bit.